# Is there a specific method for retrieving groups in JavaScript RegEx matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

So lets say I have this string in JavaScript:

```
var candidates = "hillary clinton sanders clinton bush"
```

And then I use this RegEx match and get my matching groups within this array:

```
candidates.match(/clinton ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)/)
=> [
    'clinton sanders clinton',
    'sanders',
    'clinton',
    index: 8,
    input: 'hillary clinton sanders clinton bush'
]
```

Is there any method or way of retrieving just the matching groups? Without having to know exactly how many there are? In python, I accomplish this by doing:

```
import re
test = "rowing"
temp = re.compile(r"([a-z]+)ing")
temp.match(test).groups()
---> "row"
```

Comment: You already have an array of the matching groups (with one additional item, but you can just [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it if you want). What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way match works in js, when you have groups in regex, is it will always have the full match at index 0 and the rest of the array will contain groups. So you can just do something like 
`var match = candidates.match(/clinton ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)/); 
if (match) match = match.slice(1, match.length);`

match will only contain groups. You can put this logic in a function.